# google sheets: Apps Script to create new sheets from template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets doc that contains a `Start` and `Template` sheet. The idea is to enter the name of an employee in `Start` and press the Generate button. For each employee entered, the `Template` sheet should be duplicated, named similar to the employee (e.g.,`McCormick, Peter`) and the name of the employee should be written in the new sheet in cell A2. The name of each employee should then also be added to the `Start` sheet with an indirect reference to Cell B2 of each employee sheet.

That's probably possible with Apps Script, but I'm struggling a bit to write the code. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the possible solution:

```
function create_sheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Start');
  var name = sheet.getActiveCell().getDisplayValue();
  var template = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var new_sheet = template.copyTo(ss).setName(name);
  new_sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(name);
}
```

This script duplicates the 'Template' sheet and changes its name to anything from the current cell on the sheet 'Start'.

But I don't understand what do you mean 'indirect reference to Cell B2'. Can you clarify it? What it should look like?

Here is the variant of the same code that converts employer names on the 'Start' sheet into links to the corresponding sheets:

```
function create_sheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Start');
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var name = cell.getDisplayValue();
  var template = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var new_sheet = template.copyTo(ss).setName(name);
  new_sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(name);

  var url = ss.getUrl() + '#gid=' + new_sheet.getSheetId();
  var link = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(name).setLinkUrl(url).build();
  cell.setRichTextValue(link);
}
```

[image]

Here is the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19H67bX2AeALFCGkYZwawnODAyvULbaMljx2XTM_IOZg/edit?usp=sharing).

**Update**

Here is the updated code:

```
function add_sheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var start_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Start');
  var template_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');

  // get a list of names from the 'Start' sheet 
  var names = start_sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat().filter(String);

  while(names.length) {
    var name = names.shift();

    // try to pick existed sheet with the name
    try { var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name); dest_sheet.getRange('A1') }

    // create the sheet if there is no sheet with this name
    catch(e) { var dest_sheet = template_sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(name) } 

    dest_sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(name);
  }
}
```

It creates sheets from the A column of the sheet 'Start' and the sheet 'Template'.

Here is the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GdKgcSAyQH4uo4Af96Z-CukTd8YpYFQsNh4KjTvNzbo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks @yuri khristich! Maybe my description was a bit unclear, by clicking `Generate` a sheet should be created for all names in column A2:A. Indirect reference means that all names in Column A should be copied to column E. Based on the name in column E, the algorithm should then select the related sheet and copy the information from Cell 2B (monthly wage) of that sheet name and paste it in column F. Any idea how to incorporate that?

Comment: _copy the information from Cell 2B (monthly wage)_ — where the Cell 2B is? Initially all the cells in the 'related sheet' will be same as in the template sheet. Do you mean some formula? It would be easier to understand if you make manually the spreadsheet with a couple of sheets with dummy data and share it.

Comment: I've created an example sheet here with the basic functionality needed: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ibWBxb8uDqJoUSjVZVHtmTesgVOIPAN15B2Soo_pB-E/edit?usp=sharing. The process looks like this: enter the names in `Start`, press `Generate`, then the template sheet will be copied for each name entered, renamed, and the name copied to A2, then the name will also be copied to E2:E. Hope that helps. Sorry for the late reply :)